# How to scan and print an array with a max of 20 variables?

Tags: c

In C, how do I scan an print an array of 20 numbers given by the user.

Example desired output:
Enter data: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
The data entered is: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

This is what I have so far for my loop:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++){
  scanf("%d", &arry[i]);
}
```

This however keeps asking for 21 inputs before the loop terminates.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: First, try with 2 variables and without for loop and then with for loop, you will know the error you are doing.

Comment: How may distinct integers are *inclusively* between `0` and `20` (inclusive: both `0` and `20` are included in your count) ? Yup, there's your 21.

Comment: Easiest way to understand problems like this is with a printf: `printf("value for arry[%d]: ", i);`

Comment: The idiomatic `for` loop in C runs `for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)` (where you omit the `int` if you don't have C99 or you need the value of `i` after the loop completes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++){
  scanf("%d", &arry[i]);
}
```

We should always remember that when we are declaring an array of size n, then an array of n elements with indexes 0 to n-1 is allocated. We should not access to those memory locations which are not allocated to us , The C does not allow you to do so,your program may crash.Though your compiler may not give any error message.

It is a good practice to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine except that `=`. It means:

> Run `FOR-LOOP` from `0` up to `20`.

Which means a total of `21` values. Just remove that `=` and you are good to go:

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
  scanf("%d", &arry[i]);
}
```

Comment: New users must take this to account, that if they find the answer correct and it resolves their issue, then kindly mark that as answer. That's how things work here . Welcome to SO :)